# Scala website: create routes

Tags: scala, heroku, sbt

I'm following the Heroku scala tutorial at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scala

I was able to get everything working, but I have absolutely no idea where to go from here.  I'd like to avoid using a framework (for now) if I can since the point of this is to learn scala and create a website with it.  Their webwords example they list as a followup is completely different from the basic hello world example.

Mainly, I have no idea how heroku/scala/sbt know how to actually start the app and respond to requests since the samples are so different.  I've looked at some frameworks and they seem pretty similar in that regard.

I'd really just like to know what the standard method for creating routes is (if there is such a thing).  Any other tips about how to create a small MVC framework would also be of great help to me.  A lot of the tutorials I see seem to make assumptions about what you already know (e.g. you would already know how to create routes and the like) but I can't find any tutorials that are even simpler.

Comment: What do you mean though by "create routes"? I can think of several possible explanations.

Comment: At its most basic I want certain URLs that the app will respond to like `/`, `/hello`, `/login`, etc.  Ruby on Rails has a concept of routes that is similar that may make more sense.

Comment: Ok - that makes sense, but I've never used RoR, so I wasn't familiar with that particular terminology.

Comment: That article on the Heroku Dev Center uses [Twitter Finagle](http://twitter.github.com/finagle/) for handling HTTP requests.  Are you saying you don't want to use Finagle or you want to create your own HTTP handling library or you want to use another Scala HTTP handling library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ultimately, the purpose of creating any web site, regardless of the technology used, is to offer some sort of content or functionality. You can't just say "I want to create a web site." any more than you could say "I want to build a building."

Once you have defined what the web site is supposed to do, then and only then is appropriate to consider how to implement it. The purpose of most frameworks to provide easy to use solutions to common and often difficult problems. For example, using a web application server like Jetty, Tomcat, or Glassfish trivializes most of the "route" issues. Any time that you save by using available tools can then be reinvested in creating better content.

On the other hand, if you really do want to implement an entire web server from scratch, the place to start is with the basic Hello app. In `Hello.apply`, you can start by looking at the `HttpRequest` ([JBoss JavaDoc](http://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.2/api/index.html)). `getURI()` will give you the request URL, and you can work out, from there, how to handle the different routes that you want to support.

Comment: I know what the site is supposed to do.  A web application server (Jetty or whatever) would be just fine, but that's not a framework.  I'm talking about something like Lift or Play.  I can use Jetty, Glassfish, etc. -- but I don't even know what they *are* (I've at least heard of Jetty) or how to use them .. at all.  I'd like to have that basic understanding before I start with a framework.  I'm also doing this for academic purposes so I'd rather not be stuck in a framework .. I'd like to learn Scala more generally first.

Comment: An important part of learning any modern language is learning some of the tools and libraries of that language's community. However, it definitely sounds like - for what you want to learn - your best bet is to take my advice from the third paragraph. Start with the Hello app. Understand what the HttpRequest is giving you and figure out what you want to write back in the HttpResponse.

Comment: What is `Hello.apply`?  I don't see any reference to it or a "Hello" app in the documentation you gave me.  This is also very overwhelming .. I'm not sure how I'm supposed to start learning from that :/

Comment: In the Heroku page that you referenced, in the section "Write Your App", there's source code for a file Web.scala. In that file, there is a definition for a class `Hello` and in that class is an `apply` method which takes an HttpRequest and returns an HttpResponse. That's where the magic happens.

Comment: I've already done all that .. I'm just not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Try some stuff and see what happens. Change the `apply` method to give different responses (other than "Hello, world.") to different URIs.